# Animating MKPolygonView

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

As the title implies I'm trying to animate a MKPolygonView, specifically the color and the opacity.

Right now I have a gesture detect whether the user has touched the polygon, by iterating through the overlayViews and finding out if the touch point is within the polygon.

In anycase, I get the MKPolygonView, I change the fillcolor and the color changes but it doesn't quite do it the way I intended seeing to how overlays draw in tiles, defined as mapRects, so when you color it in, rather than coloring in the whole polygon, it colors sections of it at a time, according to where the polygon was laid in regards to an invisible grid on the map.

Having the color for the mkpolygonview come in a tile at a time is okay but as I said it's unideal.

The problem is further complicated due to the fact that MKPolygonView cannot be subclassed. I'm a little out of ideas, and would appreciate some input from you guys.

If you made it this far, thanks.